# Host to kernel sending information issue

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

The kernel below in C language changes a cell of an array:

```
    __global__ void test(int *mt[matrix_size])
{
    mt[0][0]=12;
}
```

The code below copies kernel results to host but it doesn't send the array to host correctly:

```
    int *matrix[matrix_size],*d_matrix[matrix_size];
for(int i=0;i<matrix_size;i++)
    matrix[i] = (int *)malloc(n*n*sizeof(int)); 
for(int i=0;i<matrix_size;i++)
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_matrix[i],sizeof(int));
test<<<1,1>>>(d_matrix);
cudaMemcpy(*matrix,*d_matrix,n*n*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
printf("\n\n %d \n\n",matrix[0][0]); //the result is zero instead of 12
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: there are so many issues with your code, first matrix and d_matrix not allocated equal dynamic memory (see size of cudaMalloc allocation),  why you are copying before kernel invocation from device memory to host memory (it should be opposite isn't it ?)

Comment: could u please explain it more?

Comment: When processing a two-dimensional array on the device side, you may need to map the array to a one-dimensional array. You can't directly access the memory on the host side of the device, because your array is just copied and not mapped. The kernel function cannot access the correct address space. Or you can refer to `cudamemcpy2D()`, click [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g3a58270f6775efe56c65ac47843e7cee) for more info.

Comment: thank u ..but the result yet is zero...

Comment: @rbhd Since there is already an answer, and I am able to run it correctly, my thought is a little different, If you need it, I can post the simple code(perhaps the effect is not as good as the answer given).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have gotten a lot wrong here.

The root cause is that `d_matrix` is in host memory and can't be passed directly to a kernel. If you check runtime errors you will see that firstly the first `cudaMemcpy` call fails because of the wrong direction argument, then when you fix that, the kernel fails with a invalid address error.

To fix this, you need to allocate a copy of `d_matrix` on the GPU and copy `d_matrix` to that copy. This is because the array you are passing to the kernel decays to a pointer and is not passed by value.

Something like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

const int n = 9;
const int matrix_size = 16;

__global__ 
void test(int *mt[matrix_size])
{
    mt[threadIdx.x][0] = 12 + threadIdx.x;
}

int main()
{
    int *matrix[matrix_size],*d_matrix[matrix_size];

    for(int i=0;i<matrix_size;i++) {
        matrix[i] = (int *)malloc(n * n * sizeof(int)); 
        cudaMalloc((void**)&d_matrix[i], n * n * sizeof(int));
    }

    int **dd_matrix;
    cudaMalloc(&dd_matrix, matrix_size * sizeof(int*));
    cudaMemcpy(dd_matrix, d_matrix, matrix_size * sizeof(int *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    test<<<1,matrix_size>>>(dd_matrix);

    for(int i=0;i<matrix_size;i++) {
        cudaMemcpy(matrix[i], d_matrix[i], n*n*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        printf("%d = %d \n", i, matrix[i][0]); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which when run gives this:

```
$ nvcc -g -G -arch=sm_52 -o bozocu bozocu.cu 

$ ./bozocu
0 = 12 
1 = 13 
2 = 14 
3 = 15 
4 = 16 
5 = 17 
6 = 18 
7 = 19 
8 = 20 
9 = 21 
10 = 22 
11 = 23 
12 = 24 
13 = 25 
14 = 26 
15 = 27
```

is, I believe, more in line with what you were expecting.